# How can google DataLayer be converted into javascript object with key values for variables?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

When you use Google Analytics DataLayer on your website you have it as a global variable dataLayer.
You can add your own events variables into it.

How can you convert all variables inside it to an object like

```
{var:value}
```

Comment: The dataLayer is a GTM specific JSON object. Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: I'd like to access it's values something like MyDataLayerVar.varName. Especially variables that are not standard (pushed by users)

Comment: I have .js in websites doing some analysis, and would like to consider some vars from DataLayer to be sent to the servers

Answer (score 0):

You access it like any other object:

```
var dataLayer = [{
   myVar1: 'val1',
   myVar2: 'val2
}]

var myVar1 = dataLayer[0].myVar1;
var myVar2 = dataLayer[0].myVar2;
```

Comment: you definitely don't know what I'm talking about. dataLayer variable is an array.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for the bad syntax, long day for me. But you need to 1)  brush up on your GTM as the dataLayer is an object (more precisely an array of objects, but commonly just called an object) and you simply need to Google that if you put as little effort into looking more into this yourself as you did with your post, 2) provide constructive comments rather than negative remark about ones lack of understanding in the light of poor data.

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your heated response to nyuens answer. Firstly, since this is javascript so an array is also an object, secondly the dataLayer is an array of objects or, as we call it in JavaScript, an object (it's called JavaScript Object Notation after all). So you have an array with numeric indexes where every element is an object (which might in turn contain other arrays and objects).

I strongly disagress with nyuen's suggestion to adress elements in the dataLayer with the numeric index, though. If you push data to your dataLayer before the tag manager code dataLayer[0] will contain your custom data, if you don't it will contain the gtm.load event and related data. So this is not reliable.

However it seems want you really want is to flatten the object, i.e. remove the nested structure with numerical keys and have a one-dimensional structure. [Luckily somebody has written a function that does this](https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197):

```
var flattenObject = function(ob) {
    var toReturn = {};

    for (var i in ob) {
        if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;

        if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object') {
            var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
            for (var x in flatObject) {
                if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;

                toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
            }
        } else {
            toReturn[i] = ob[i];
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
};
```

This makes a "one-dimensional" object from a nested object. Usually this would mean that keys with the same name will be overwritten by the respective last element. I.e.

```
dataLayer = [
    {'key':value1},
    {'key':value2},
]
```

would result in a simple

```
{'key':value2}
```

since the second "key" overwrites the first. However the function above mitigates this by storing the index as part of the key name, so you would get

```
{'0.key':value1, '1.key':value2}
```

which somewhat unfortunately means you cannot use dot syntax and have to adress the elements with angled brackets:

```
 yourvariablename['0.key']
```